# Regd. Conditional Router in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am working on conditional router in wso2 esb and my scenario is as follows.
I extracted studentno in payload and wanted to perform conditional router on the top of that but this is working for header and query params and not for query variables or a value extracted from payload. I tried for the solution but I got switch-case as a solution. Is this is a limitation in conditional router that works only with header and params? If no please provide your inputs on the condition  in conditional router.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types to achieve your requirement. You should be able to use either the type **soap** [2] or the type **property** [1] to route based on the payload content. Refer to the sample below. The other available types can be found in the documentation [3].

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="conditionalRouter"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property expression="$body//symbol" name="requestProperty"/>
         <log level="custom">
            <property expression="$body//symbol" name="requestProperty"/>
         </log>
         <conditionalRouter continueAfter="false">
            <conditionalRoute breakRoute="false">
               <condition>
                  <match regex="WSO2.*" source="//symbol" type="soap"/>
               </condition>
               <target sequence="cnd1_seq"/>
            </conditionalRoute>
            <conditionalRoute breakRoute="false">
               <condition>
                  <match regex="IBM.*" source="requestProperty" type="property"/>
               </condition>
               <target sequence="cnd2_seq"/>
            </conditionalRoute>
         </conditionalRouter>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

**request 1**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
        <request>
            <symbol>WSO2</symbol>
        </request>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**request 2**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
        <request>
            <symbol>WSO2</symbol>
        </request>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Note**

The **Conditional Router Mediator** is removed from the EI 6.5.0 version onwards [4]. Therefore if you have already developed your mediation using the switch case mediator, better to use the same since it would be easier for you if you decide to migrate to a new EI version.

[1]-https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/v2.1.7-wso2v111/modules/commons/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/commons/evaluators/config/TextProcessingEvaluatorFactory.java#L60

[2]-https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/v2.1.7-wso2v111/modules/commons/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/commons/evaluators/config/TextProcessingEvaluatorFactory.java#L66

[3]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI620/Sample+157%3A+Conditional+Router+for+Routing+Messages+based+on+HTTP+URL%2C+HTTP+Headers+and+Query+Parameters

[4]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/About+this+Release

Comment: Thank you @shanaka-premarathna for your response. I am using RestAPI and Json, still the approach is same I followed as per the wso2 official documentation but the change was I tried with <equal comparison instead of match and it was not working. Anyways, if it is getting deprecated then no point on this to check. Thank you Again :)